# How to use multiprocessing in Python with big data?

Tags: python, concurrency, bigdata, concurrent.futures

I wanna make anapp, but it has to calculate a lot of things, so I want to use multiprocessing to speedup but can't make it work. I did and somewhat worked is copying all the data for all processes, but it took too much memory...

What I did:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
import time

variables = {} # tried to save the values for accessing later

def test(n):
    distances = variables['distances']
    position = variables['position']
    time.sleep(350)
    return position

def main():
    variables['distances'] = pd.read_csv('very_large_file.csv') # let 1 for this exemple # imagine a file with a lot of data, like 2Gb
    variables['position'] = pd.read_csv('another_very_large_file.csv') # let 2 # another file with a lot of data, like 2Gb

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
        for result in executor.map(test, range(5)):
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code returns a error that 'a' is not in variables.

If I load the file using a 'file.csv' it takes way too much ram, but my pc can't run it, so I want to know how it can access a that object, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: The code works fine on my machine (but multiprocessing might work differently on other systems). Also how exactly does this relate to `file.csv`? There's no file opened in your example.

Comment: I suggest you update your code to work with small csv files (maybe with 3 lines) make it work without using thread, then post the updated code here, along with sample csv files. You might get better help that way.

Comment: @KlausD., I tried to include just a bit of code to reproduce my error, but the large data is saved on a csv file, and it takes a lot of time to read the data, and a lot of ram to work.

Comment: This could be because your multiprocessing start method defaults to `spawn` rather than `fork`. IIRC MacOS and Windows spawn whereas Linux forks. When a new process is spawned it recreates the variables in the global scope so the data that you've read into memory in `main()` is lost. If you fork then the all data is copied across to the new process. Be aware that in Python separate processes cannot have access to the same memory because of the GIL.

Comment: Also be aware that forking is risky and can lead to deadlocks. It's generally recommended to go with `spawn`. Either way you cut it, if you want all the csv data accessible to each child process then you'll have to duplicate of all the data across each process which may well lead to out of memory killer.
In this situation I would either shard the csv data into each process if you know each process only needs a subsection of the data, or I'd use something like DuckDB to query the data without loading in mem/polars LazyFrame

Comment: Just realised I was a bit wrong RE shared memory, there is this module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html
It looks a bit involved so I would still consider using a query engine in each child process instead.